# Registering the time when data is written to a file

Tags: file, gnuradio

I need to register the power received from the antenna and the time of arrival of this power in the  file sink, how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Not at all, probably. SDRs are usually not calibrated power measurement devices.

Your magnitude square is *proportional* to power at the antenna, but finding the proportionality factor is up to you. You need to use the measurement devices you have and invent a method of *calibration*.

Comment: I have a method for obtaining power, I need to know the time of arrival of power to the antenna for further data analysis

Comment: you can't do that unless your SDR has the exact same notion of "time" as your transmitter.